# Addressing Duplicated Rows: Including a SELECT Statement within an Inner Join In SQL

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm working on writing a writing a SQL script that will generate a historical monthly dataset. My problem is that I need to bring into my dataset an additional column and if I simply use an inner join statement or a left outer join statement my dataset returns duplicated rows.

To address this issue I think I need to include a `SELECT` statement within an `inner join`, however when I try doing this my script will not execute. I'm wondering if I am misusing the `SELECT`  in my `inner join`.

A little background on my code, tables a and d are the same tables, however I need to use them both to calculate the field `PrinPmt` and `IntPmt`.

My code:

```
select

a.acct_id AccountID,
t.act_open_date OpenDate,
a.process_date ProcessDate, 
a.acct_type AccountType, 
d.payment_nxt_due_amt PaymentDue,  
a.cur_bal CurrentBalance,
oza.fee_paid FeesPaid,
d.process_date, 
d.cur_bal, 
a.cur_bal - isnull(d.cur_bal,0) as PrinPmt,
a.int_paid_total - isnull(d.int_paid_total,0) as IntPmt,

from tb_ln_ozs_accts a
inner join tb.offset_month b 
      on a.process_date = b.process_date
inner join tb.offset_month c 
      on b.offset = c.offset+1
left outer join tb_ln_ozs_accts d  
      on c.process_date = d.process_date
      and a.acct_id = d.acct_id
      and a.order_no= d.order_no
left outer join tb_oza_pmt_schd_ard oza 
      on d.process_date=oza.process_date 
      and d.acct_id = oza.acct_id 
      and d.order_no= oza.order_no
      and d.scheduled_payment_date = oza.payment_eff_date
inner join (
select
dzn.acct_nbr_id,
dzn.order_no,
t.act_open_date
from 
tb_dzn_order_scd dzn
GROUP BY dzn.acct_id , dzn.order_nbr
) on a.acct_id = dzn.acct_nbr_id and  a.order_no= DZN.order_no
where 

and a.process_date >= '2015-01-01'


order by a.process_date, a.acct_id, a.order_no
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! ([mcve].)

Comment: on it! thanks @jarlh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close, but need one extra step.

In the joined sub-query, you actually need to name the sub-query itself which creates a virtual table with that name. Then link that virtual table as normal.

e.g., in the below I named the sub-query 'dzn_subquery' and changed the joins on dzn to dzn_subquery (all changes are on the bottom line).

```
inner join (
select
dzn.acct_nbr_id,
dzn.order_no,
t.act_open_date
from 
tb_dzn_order_scd dzn
GROUP BY dzn.acct_id , dzn.order_nbr
-- changed following line
) AS dzn_subquery on a.acct_id = dzn_subquery.acct_nbr_id and  a.order_no= dzn_subquery.order_no
```

Comment: Dang, I was working on this for like 3 hours and its that simple. Thank you so much!

Comment: Haha - happens to us all, it really does: Looking at all the important things (repeatedly), but not realising that there's another important thing you weren't aware of. That's what learning (particularly learning by trying and failing) is all about. If someone says it doesn't happen to them, then they're not trying hard enough to learn/develop imo.